# SSLException:Write error: ssl=0x7f8170c780: I/O error during system call, Connection timed out

Tags: okhttp

I use okhttp and retrofit2 to post a audio file,but sometimes the file broken (server side),What is the reason?

```
File file = new File(path);
RequestBody requestFile = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("audio/*"), file);
body = MultipartBody.Part.createFormData("audio_file", file.getName(), requestFile);

HashMap<String,RequestBody> params = new HashMap<>();
params.put("lecture_id",RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("multipart/form-data"), mId + ""));
params.put("duration",RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("multipart/form-data"),attachment.getDuration() + ""));
params.put("reply_message_id",RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("multipart/form-data"),msg.getReplyMsgId() + ""));

Subscription subscription = ApiService.getInstance().sendAudioMessage(body,params).subscribe(new HttpObserver<IMMessage>() {
    @Override
    protected void onError(ApiException ex) {
        CrashReport.postCatchedException(ex);
        ToastUtil.showToast(getActivity(),ex.getMsg());
        onSendMessageFail(msg);
    }

    @Override
    public void onNext(IMMessage imMessage) {
        onSendMessageSuccess(msg);
    }
});
mCompositeSubscription.add(subscription);
```

Comment: I also having this same problem,do u have solution on this??